# MySQL SELECT INTO Equivalent?

Tags: sql, mysql

In SQL Server, I can copy tables or temporary tables to new table, using a `SELECT* INTO..` syntax.

Someone know how can I make this same action in MySQL?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

See [CREATE TABLE ... AS SELECT ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html). Note that this will not recreate indexes and foreign keys, as was already noted.

Comment: CREATE [TEMPORARY] TABLE <table_name> Select [fields or *] from [Original_Table_Name] [Conditions] [Limit] [number].

Tks.

Comment: Example: `CREATE TABLE br_logs3 AS SELECT * FROM br_logs WHERE username LIKE 'ac%';` Note that the `AS` is optional.