# Save SQL query result as new table

Tags: mysql

I have a result from my query:

```
SELECT * FROM Mon
```

I want to save SQL query result as new table.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
CREATE TABLE YourNewTable
AS
SELECT *
FROM Mon
```

Extra details can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1546526/mysql-select-into-equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE Monitoring_MT_table
   SELECT * FROM Monitoring_MT
   LEFT JOIN Monitoring_TW ON Monitoring_MT.id = Monitoring_TW.id
   UNION
   SELECT * FROM Monitoring_MT
   RIGHT JOIN Monitoring_TW ON Monitoring_MT.id = Monitoring_TW.id
```

You can read about create as select in mysql [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-select.html)

Comment: Doesnt work, gives me Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 3
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'SELECT'.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT *
INTO YourNewTableName
FROM Mon;

Take a look [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp) to understand more about your problem :).